# java packaging a jar with org.bouncycastle as a dependency causes "main class not found" on execution

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle, executable-jar

I am currently trying to package my java application, which uses `docker-java` as a dependency. Docker-java uses `org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.60` and `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60` as a dependency. When I package my project into a jar, using IntelliJ build or maven, the following four files are getting created inside the `META-INF` folder: `BC1024KE.DSA`, `BC1024KE.SF`, `BC2048KE.DSA`and `BC2048KE.SF`.

When I try to execute the jar I get the following error: `Error: Mainclass de.dert.Main couldn't be found or loaded`.

But when I delete the four files I can execute my program.

Do you know how I can get this working without deleting the files?

Comment: `de.dert.Main` is your main class, right? Try with `mvn package` command in your terminal

Comment: Yes it is and mnv package also doesn't solve the problem. I think part of the problem ist that the bouncycastle jars are signed.